# 1-D stress (displacement) analysis in annulus by considering viscoelasticity

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am a new Mathematica user, and I was trying to solve a stress (or displacement) field problem in an annulus.

Here is the problem in the polar coordinate: The inner radius of the annulus is $b$, and the outer radius of the annulus is $c$. The boundary condition is that at the inner surface there is an applied pressure $p(t)$. The outer surface is traction free. The material is viscoelastic. Since the annulus stresses are not a function of $θ$, the stresses are functions of $r$ and $t$ only, which makes this problem a 1-D problem.

The governing equation:

$$\frac{\partial σ_r}{\partial r} - \frac{σ_θ}{r}=0$$

Constitutive equations:

$$σ_r = \int_0^t \frac{\partial ϵ_r(r, t')}{\partial t'} E_g(t-t') dt'$$

$$σ_θ = \int_0^t \frac{\partial ϵ_θ(r, t')}{\partial t'} E_g(t-t') dt'$$

Strain-stress relations:

$$ϵ_r = \frac{\partial u(r, t)}{r}$$
$$ϵ_θ = \frac{u(r, t)}{r}$$

To make the calculation simple, let's assume the modulus $E_g(t-t')=1$. The annulus dimensions: $b=1$, $c=2$. The pressure: $p(t)=0.1t$.

My code is here

```
b = 1;
c = 2;
p[t_] = 0.1 t;
eqn1 = {ϵr -> D[u[r, t], r], ϵθ -> u[r, t]/r};
eqc = {σr = Integrate[D[(ϵr /. eqn1), t], {t, 0, t}], 
       σθ = Integrate[D[(ϵθ /. eqn1), t], {t, 0, t}]};
sys = {D[eqc[[1]], r] + eqc[[2]]/r}; 
uu1 = NDSolve[{sys[[1]] == 0, (eqc[[1]] /. r -> c) == 0, 
               (eqc[[1]] /. r -> b) == -p[t], 
               (u[r, t] /. t -> 0) == 0}, u, {r, b, c}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

I could not run this code in Mathematica. Can someone please help me? I think the problem is the constitutive equations: they contain $t'$ and $t$, but I just used $t$ for the integral .

Comment: The equations are a bit hard to read. I tried transforming them to traditional math notation based on my understanding, please check if I've transformed them correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, these equations are correct.

Comment: NDSolve currently (V12.1) can not solve integro-differential equations out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. So, can you please suggest a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: You'd need to add a @ in front of the person that you want to send a message too, like @xzczd, otherwise people will not get you message and will not respond.

Comment: Concerning your problem, I know to little about viscoelasticity to suggest a way forward with FEM.

Comment: @user21 Thank you so much!